# invalid parameter while creating bitmap image with directory asp.net

Tags: asp.net, bitmap

i am trying to access images from a directory one by one. 
here is the code

```
string[] filesindirectory = Directory.GetFiles(("D:/Folder/32373577989/"));

    foreach (string item in filesindirectory)
    {
        Bitmap bitMapImage = new Bitmap(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item));
    }
```

but it gives error within the loop when i create bitmap obj, it says "invalid parameter".Even i checked the location to files inside the directory is correct but still shows error.
please tell me whats wrong.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the `System.IO.Path.GetFileName` call:

```
foreach (string item in filesindirectory)
{
    Bitmap bitMapImage = new Bitmap(item);
}
```

`GetFileName` is truncating the full path to just the name, like `D:\Folder\234324234\1.png` to just `1.png`. When you remove the path like that it is most likely trying to load the image by the current working directory of the process.

I would also consider using the [overload of `GetFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes in a filter.

Right now your code is pulling in all files, including hidden ones that might not be an image, like a Thumbs.db file or a desktop.ini file - files that Windows Explorer internally uses for storing metadata about the directory.